# how to move the lines left at one character width in vim?

Tags: vim

When i edit python file in gim

```
:3,10 <
```

That command can move lines between 3th and 10th to the left  at 4 characters width.
How to move the lines from 3 till 10 line left at one character width in vim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following commands

```
:echo(&shiftwidth)
Make note of result in brain
:set shiftwidth=1
:3,10 <
:set shiftwidth=(note made in brain)
```

Alternatively

```
:3,10 s/^ //
```

Answer (score 1):

The [anwolib plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3800) provides a neat `:With ... Do` command. With it, you can also automate (via a custom command or mapping) this easily:

```
:With sw=1 Do 3,10 <
```

Comment: would you mind solving the problem :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438579/how-to-output-all-the-lines-into-python-console-in-vim?

Comment: would you mind solving the problem again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481506/how-to-bind-the-prompt-key-to-2to3-py?