# how to bind the prompt key to 2to3.py?

Tags: vim

I have write a vimsrcipt to bind F3 key to change python2 file into python3 file.

```
map <f3> :w<cr>:! D:\Python34\python D:\Python34\Tools\Scripts\2to3.py  -w %<cr>
```

I feel that it should be improved for useage.
It works in the steps:

step1: open the test.py( in the form of python2) in gvim
step2: press F3
step3: close the test.py( in the form of python2)
step4: open  the test.py(now ,it is in the form of python3)

Now i want to make a little progress, when i press F3 ,the test.py will be changed into python3 form,not to reopen it.
How can i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid steps 3 and 4 either by explicitly reloading the file via `:e`:

```
nnoremap <f3> :w<cr>:! D:\Python34\python D:\Python34\Tools\Scripts\2to3.py  -w %<cr>:e<cr>
```

or by turning on

```
:set autoread
```

<sup>Again, [you should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); and specify the proper mode (normal mode).</sup>

Comment: would you mind asking the question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25560346/why-cant-open-the-html-with-chrome-in-gvim-map-function ?