# why can't open the html with chrome in gvim map function?

Tags: google-chrome, vim

I have mapped F6 and F7 in vimrc file.

```
:nnoremap <F6>:w<cr> :!start cmd  C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe %<CR>

:nnoremap <F7>:w<cr> :exe '!"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" %'<CR>

In CMD ,it works fine for me.

C:\Users\pengsir>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" g:\\my.html
```

When i open  g:\my.html  in gvim and enter into normal status ,press  F6 or  F7,why my chrome can not open the my.html?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<HEAD>
<META CHARSET="UTF-8" />
<TITLE> FIRST WEB</TITLE>
<body>
   it is my first web
</body>
</html>
```

When i press F6 IN GVIM ,

[image]
[image]

Comment: It might just have to do with spaces or backslashes needing escaping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let's solve this step by step:

```
:nnoremap <F6>:w<cr> :!start cmd  C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe %<CR>
```

First, there's whitespace missing between the lhs (`<F6>`) and the `:w...` rhs; you're currently mapping the key combo `<F6>:w<cr>`.

```
:nnoremap <F6> :w<cr> :!start cmd  C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe %<CR>
```

That gives me an open command prompt, but no Chrome. You need to pass either `/C` or `/K` so that the remainder is executed as a command; `cmd.exe /?` tells you this. Let's first use `/K` to be able to read any errors.

```
:nnoremap <F6> :w<cr> :!start cmd /K C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe %<CR>
```

I now get `'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`; we need quoting. We could manually enclose the path in double quotes, but as you probably want to handle any file names passed via `%`, it's better to let Vim do the quoting. For that, we need `:execute` (to insert the expressions) and `shellescape()`.

Another hairy quirk of `cmd.exe` is that once you use quoting, you need to quote the *entire* command-line again, too. (Don't feel stupid if this is over your head; Microsoft and compatibility down to MS-DOS is to blame for this mess. Vim underwent improvements in that area, too; be sure to use at least a version 7.3.800, or 7.4.)

```
:nnoremap <F6> :w<cr> :execute '!start cmd /K "' shellescape('C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe', 1) shellescape(expand('%'), 1) . '"'<CR>
```

That one opens the current HTML file in Chrome for me. For finishing touches, just get rid of the left-behind command prompt (`/C`), and join the two Ex commands, replacing `:w` with the on-demand `:update`:

```
:nnoremap <F6> :update<Bar>execute '!start cmd /C "' shellescape('C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe', 1) shellescape(expand('%'), 1) . '"'<CR>
```

You can make that a bit more resilient by always passing the full absolute path:

```
:nnoremap <F6> :update<Bar>execute '!start cmd /C "' shellescape('C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe', 1) shellescape(expand('%:p'), 1) . '"'<CR>
```

Comment: I have tested it ,can't open it.

Comment: That's way to little information to help you further! Where's the problem? I've intentionally developed this step by step so you can follow along and understand each step!

Comment: It is a path problem, when i open the  g:\my.html  in chrome ,the path is `file:///G:/my.html`, when i press F6 , the path is `http://my.html/` ,how can i change it into `file:///G:/my.html` ?

Comment: Have you tried my edit from today, where I introduced `expand('%:p')`?!

Comment: well done, :nnoremap <F6> :update<Bar>execute '!start cmd /C "' shellescape('C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe', 1) shellescape(expand('%:p'), 1) . '"'<CR>